# Прогрессивная прогрузка JPG-файла

Tags: вёрстка, загрузка, jpeg

Я думаю, все сталкивались с прогрузкой гугл карт, когда изображение прогружается, постепенно увеличивая при этом свое качество. Вопрос: как это реализовать?
Пробовал в фотошопе сохранить *.jpg файл как Progressive. Но этого ничего не изменило. Искал скрипт по просторам Интернета, тоже его нет. Только одни доводы и объяснения, что такое прогрессивная загрузка. Кто из верстальщиков уже реализовывал такую свистелку для сайта?
Если можно с примером.
Спасибо.